# Thymeleaf remove block of code

Tags: thymeleaf

I use thymeleaf 3 and bootstrap 4
I have this code

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6" th:text="#{summary}">
      Summary
      <ul class="list-group">
         <li class="list-group-item"><span th:text="#{notSpecials}">Not special</span></li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><span th:text="#{specials}">Special</span></li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><span th:text="#{granulate}">Granulate</span></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6" th:text="#{byTestType}">
      By test type
      <ul class="list-group">
         <li class="list-group-item"><span th:text="#{compressions}">Compressions</span></li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><span th:text="#{absorptions}">Absorptions</span></li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><span th:text="#{durabilityScalings}">Durability  Scaling</span></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

thymeleaf return me

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">Summary</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">By test type</div>
</div>
```

It seem like thymeleaf remove code .

All value are correctly in the localization file of spring boot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is because of your localization.... change your block to

```
             <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <span th:text="#{summary}">Summay</span>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                      <li class="list-group-item"><span th:text="#{notSpecials}">Not special</span></li>
                      <li class="list-group-item"><span th:text="#{specials}">Special</span></li>
                      <li class="list-group-item"><span th:text="#{granulate}">Granulate</span></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <span th:text="#{byTestType}">By test type</span>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                      <li class="list-group-item"><span th:text="#{compressions}">Compressions</span></li>
                      <li class="list-group-item"><span th:text="#{absorptions}">Absorptions</span></li>
                      <li class="list-group-item"><span th:text="#{durabilityScalings}">Durability / Scaling</span></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
```